# Characterizing the "prominence" of a poll response

Tags: r, math, statistics

I’m trying to characterize how prominent a selection is. 
You poll 10 people for their
favorite color and you get the following response:

```
r = c(rep("blue",5),rep("green",4),rep("red",1))
```

And you make a contingency table:

```
tab = table(r)
```

If you take the density of this...

```
d = density(tab)
```

If you ask someone else and they say "red", you characterize the prominence
of this response by the integral of the portion of the probability density function equal to or less than the rate of their response:

```
get.prominence = function(new.response){
  rate = tab[new.response]
  window.index = tail(which(d$x<=rate),n=1)
  sum(d$y[1:window.index])/sum(d$y)
}
get.prominence("red") # .16
get.prominence("blue") # .77
```

Is this a reasonable way of doing this? There must be a known technique
for this and I don't know the name of it.

Comment: When you ask "is this a reasonable way of doing this", what is the "this" you are referring to? Are you simply talking about calculating this value in R? Or are you talking about the statistical validity of such a measure? Seems odd to use a continuous density with such discrete values. If it really is that statistics part you want advice for, you should ask at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll head there.